# Amazon EC2 - seeing files between instances

Tags: amazon-ec2

I've set up 2 instances of Windows Server 2008 on EC2. I want one to act as the database server and the other as the client. For the client app to work it needs to be able to connect to the server instance with ALL of these things:

- IP address of the database instance
- access through a given UDP port
- server name e.g. \\MyServer
- an actual physical path through to its database e.g. \\UNC\SharedFolder\MyDatabaseFolder

I'm a complete novice with EC2. Is there anyway I can set this up?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

At least three of the four are completely possible and I have worked with similar setups. Maybe someone else knows more about the UDP bit.

- IP address of the database instance

That is standard on EC2. All instances have two network interfaces, one EC2 internal and one to the outside world. For communication between instances use the internal one. Data traffic over these interfaces is free.

- Access through a given UDP port

I have never tried UDP communication in EC2, but if it works you should probably keep it within a local network of your own, i.e. a [virtual private cloud (VPC)](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/vpc/).

- Server name e.g. \MyServer

This kind of host name lookup does not need a name server, although you certainly could run one (preferably within a VPC). If you put the server name and (internal) IP into your hosts file (%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts) you don't need a name server, though.

- An actual physical path through to its database e.g. \UNC\SharedFolder\MyDatabaseFolder

Folder sharing should work the same as with any other Windows machine, but even that should probably be kept within a VPC.

Setting up a VPC can be a little steep to start with, but the documentation is good and the hard bits are often not needed (such as VPN tunnels). Have a look at the [example scenarios](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenarios.html) and follow the one best matching your needs.

Comment: That's great. Definitely looks like VPC is the way to go for those last two. Many thanks.